# Maestral doesn't start at login

Tags: startup, dropbox, startup-applications

I have installed [Maestral](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral) and activated the "Start Maestral on login" option on preferences.

But Maestral doesn't start at login.

Here is the content of `~/.config/autostart/maestral-maestral.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version = 1.0
Type = Application
Name = Maestral
Exec = /usr/bin/python3 -m maestral_qt -c maestral
Icon = maestral
Terminal = false
Categories = Network;FileTransfer;
GenericName = File Synchronizer
Comment = Sync your files with Dropbox
```

I am able to start it with `/usr/bin/python3 -m maestral_qt -c maestral`

EDIT: I have Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: @David ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Add this in a new line `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` and remove the spaces around the `=` character for example `Exec=/usr/bin/python3 -m maestral_qt -c maestral` and see if this works? **try the command you provided to `Exec=` in the terminal first to make sure it works or find the one that works and change it**

Comment: @Raffa Hello, removing the spaces around `=` and appending `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` doesn't work: the application is not run at start-up. I see that modern Ubuntu distros don't allow to run `.desktop` files from Nautilus. But if I move this `.desktop` file to the Desktop, right-click and allow launching, and then double click on it, the application runs correctly. Also the `Exec` command line works correctly. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can easily add the command to **Startup Applications** as follows.

Search in applications for **Startup Applications** and click on it to run:

[image]

In **Startup Applications** click the **Add** button then enter `Maestral` in the **Name:** field, `/usr/bin/python3 -m maestral_qt -c maestral` in the **Command:** field and `Run Maestral on login.` in the **Comment:** field then click the **Save** button like so:

[image]

That's it. Now, every time you login, Maestral will start automatically.

---

**Notice:**

The above steps will create a new `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/` and you can run `ls ~/.config/autostart/` to find the file and see how it's done the right way. The file might be named after the first part of the command i.e `python3.desktop` and if you run `cat ~/.config/autostart/python3.desktop` you should see something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 -m maestral_qt -c maestral
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Maestral
Name=Maestral
Comment[en_US]=Run Maestral on login.
Comment=Run Maestral on login.
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I just discovered that the application was indeed running, just the icon was not displayed in the system tray for some reason. Anyway, accepting your answer as correct

Comment: @raffaem You are most welcome.